# How to do DNS AAAA, CNAME and SRV lookups in C++?

Tags: c++, dns, lookup

I need to a little program in C++ that takes the type and hostname as commandline parameters and then makes the DNS lookup. For example:

```
DNSapp AAAA www.google.com
```

would return the IPv6 address from www.google.com and so on.

I can do the simple A lookup just by using the gethostbyname, but I have no idea how to perform those other lookups. I've tried to google them, but with no success. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows/MacOS/BSD/Linux?

Comment: I'm programming that on Linux

Comment: getnameinfo exists in linux for RDNS lookups. getaddrinfo also exists, but doesn't seem to support SRV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gethostbyname` is obsolete, use `getaddrinfo` for `A / AAAA` lookups.

For `SRV` etc I recommend `ldns`, or the related `libunbound`.  The latter is a full resolver in a library.

You could also just use `res_search` from the Linux standard library.

Comment: Isn't gethostbyaddr used when one knows the IP address and wants to know the host name?

Comment: sorry, too little caffeine - I meant `getaddrinfo` and have corrected my answer

Comment: ldns seems to fit for my needs. I'm going to try it and hopefully I get something done.

Comment: How to actually use that ldns? I'm trying to follow the installation instructions in the README file, but every time I try to "make" it, I get the error that makefile is not found. I downloaded the latest ldsn version from nlnetlab site. How I can actually use that whole library? I'm not very familiar with C or C++ and using external libraries...

Comment: ah, if you're a beginner you may struggle with ldns.  `res_search` should suffice for simple stuff.

Comment: res_search would be great otherwise, but as much as I understand, it seems that res_search doesn't support SRV.

Comment: Wrong call. It supports SRV as well. I'm going to try res_search now instead.

Comment: After some struggling and studying, I believe I can reach my goal by using the recommended res_search. Thanks.

Comment: Stepping in after some years, res_search should be good enough but if one wants async, *c-ares* is worth trying for DNS and I have written an umbrella library for async forward/SRV/reverse/DNS lookus: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=netresolve.git;a=blob;f=README;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, `GetAddrInfoW` is the correct multi-valued version of gethostbyname.

For RDNS, `getnameinfo` goes the other way.

`GetAddrInfoEx` may or may not use SRV records, I haven't been able to find out.